# How do I merge -all- tables in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I wish to create a database about GDP, population, CPI, etc. for 100 cities. Also, the user can submit in HTML which variables he needs. 
Goal 1: the end user may ask for GDP, pop, CPI for all 100 cities in 2017. 
Goal 2: the end user asks for GDP, pop, CPI... for city_1 in 2000-2017(entire period).
I decided to create 1 table for each city. In the city, there are several fields for year, GDP, pop, cpi...
Therefore, Goal 2 can be achieved by the following: I can collect values from the box which end-user entered, ie: `category{all, GDP, pop}, city{all, city_1, city_2}, time{all, 2017, 2016,...}.`

```
$query="SELECT * FROM $query where year=$time";     
$qry_result=$mysqli->query($query);
```

However, I'm not sure how to show Goal 1. Since there may be hundreds to thousands of cities, it seems not to be the right way to list all tables.
I thought I needed some code like

```
SELECT * FROM (SHOW TABLES) FROM $year=$time;
```

Obviously this code cannot work.
So, I think that merge may work. For example, if I can merge all tables or merge all tables with year="value from user", the problem is solved. 
However, because there are so many cities, I'm not sure if it's the only way to type all merge commands one by one, isn't there any code to "merge ALL" within one database?
Thanks forward if you can help me with the merge part or even how to structure the database.

Comment: _I decided to create 1 table for each city_ I think that is the wrong decision. Create a single table containing all cities

Comment: But how to deal with years? For example, user asks for GDP for a city for the past 50 years, I still need to merge 50 years....

Comment: No, you do not need to "merge" anything, when working with databases you _filter_ from a huge result set. So here you take _all_ years and specify a filter rule to select only those years actually requested.

Comment: do you mean something like SELECT * FROM year1, year2,...  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data should be in a single table, and look something like this:

Table `cities`

```
| city    | year | gdp | population | CPI |
-------------------------------------------
| London  | 2016 | 1.0 | XXY        | XXX |
| London  | 2017 | 1.0 | XXY        | XXX |
| London  | 2018 | 1.1 | XXZ        | XXX |
| Paris   | 2018 | 1.1 | XXZ        | XXX |
```

Query using something like:

```
SELECT gdp FROM cities WHERE city = 'London' AND year = 2016;
// Get GDP for London in 2016
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city = 'London' AND year BETWEEN 2016 AND 2018;
// Get all data for London for years 2016-2018
```

Comment: And for other people who need to select all periods or all cities, you can use year=year, city=city

Comment: @user9821719 If you need all data from a table, just do "SELECT * FROM tablename;"

No need to add extra conditions like "year=year"